# Nested Graphql Resolvers

Tags: typescript, graphql

```
schema.graphql

type User {
  id: ID!
  collection: Collection!
  ...
}

type Collection {
  tokens: [Token!]!
  ...
}

type Token {
  ...
}
```

How do you make nested resolvers work?

```
resolver

const resolvers = {
  User: {
    collection {
      tokens: async (user: UserEntity, _: any) => {
        return []
      },
    }
  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to IIRC. You just make a Collection resolver and it will be invoked automatically?

Comment: What's `IIRC`? @youdateme